# Java - Generate near random number. (Better than java's Random class)

Tags: java, random, numbers

Heyo! I'm making a 2d sandbox game(like terraria). Everything is working fine. So far it can generate a random terrain and trees. I have come across an issue though.

I use Java's Random class to generate a random number which I use to determine wether or not to create a tree. Here's the issue: Trees seem to be clustered all together. I get large areas with no trees and then large areas that are packed with trees. I think this is happening because Java's Random class is not random enough.

Are there any other classes included with the JDK or any external libraries I can install that can generate TRULY random numbers? Thanks in advance :D

---EDIT----
Here is how I generate the number.

```
Random rand = new Random();
rand.setSeed(worldGenerator.getSeed());
int randomNumber = rand.nextInt(1000) + 1;
```

Comment: **How** are you using `Random` to generate your numbers?

Comment: Don't provide a custom seed unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: I believe you need to do your own tweaking on top of number returned by `rand.nextInt()` ( as answered by augray )

Comment: You are, of course, creating no more than one instance of Random and using it over and over, right?  If you are, and that really isn't good enough, you can try [SecureRandom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html), which will use the underlying platform's true random number generator, if one exists.

Comment: @ThatPixelCherry: Just realized you mentioned that your map is 2d. I added an approach for a 2d map to my answer.

Comment: Are you executing all three lines in your edit every time you need a random number?  If so, you've screwed up royally.  PRNGs work by creating a single instance, then drawing as many values as you need.  If you keep creating new instances of `Random`, it's not going to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is almost certainly not a problem with Java's `Random`, but rather a common illusion in statistics. This is referred to as the [Clustering Illusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering_illusion). Basically, random distributions create clusters of dense and sparse areas rather than everything being evenly spaced because even spacing is a form of regularity.

As for making a more evenly spaced distribution out of a random one, for a 1 dimensional map you can try something roughly to the effect of:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int i=0;
while(i<mapSize){
    int distanceToNextTree = rand.nextInt(MAX_DISTANCE_BETWEEN_TREES-MIN_DISTANCE_BETWEEN_TREES)
        +MIN_DISTANCE_BETWEEN_TREES;

    i = i+distanceToNextTree;
    if(i< mapSize){
        putTree(i);
    }
}
```

For a two dimensional map you can try something more like:

```
Random rand = new Random();
int deltaX = MIN_WIDTH_BETWEEN_TREES;
int deltaY = MIN_HEIGHT_BETWEEN_TREES;
for(int x=0; x<MAP_WIDTH; x+=deltaX){
    for(int y=0; y<MAP_HEIGHT; y+=deltaY){
        boolean chunkHasTree = rand.nextBoolean();
        int chunkCenterX = x+deltaX/2;
        int chunkCenterY = y+deltaY/2;
        if(treeWithinRange(chunkCenterX,chunkCenterY,MAX_DISTANCE_BETWEEN_TREES)){
            //force a tree if there aren't any nearby
            chunkHasTree = true;
        }
        if(chunkHasTree && chunkCenterX<MAP_WIDTH && chunkCenterY<MAP_HEIGHT){
            placeTree(chunkCenterX,chunkCenterY);
        }
    }
}
```

The main idea in both cases is to create the regularity you desire by having a maximum and minimum spacing between the trees.